# Org babel google translate functions not defined

Tags: org-babel

trying to run the google-translate package in org mode, I have the following error in the package :

```
ob-translate.el:84:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be defined:
    google-translate-insert-nulls, google-translate-http-response-body,
    google-translate-format-request-url
```

And these are the functions run by org babel when evaluating the source code.

Comment: A byte-compiler warning is *not* an error.

Comment: You're right, but as org babel is trying to execute `google-translate-format-request-url` I called it an error.